# Movie cast with characters in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So, I'm doing the classical movie app in Django (I'm loving the framework!) and I feel like I hit a stump.

So, I have my Movie model:

```
class Movie(models.Model):  
    TitlePRT = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    TitleORG = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    TitleAlt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Poster = models.ImageField(upload_to=posterPath, max_length=100)
    Synopsis = models.TextField()
    Year = models.IntegerField()
    DubStudio = models.ForeignKey("Studio", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Trivia = models.TextField()
    CreatedBy = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    CreatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    Modifiedby = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    ModifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

My Actor model:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    Bio = models.TextField()
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    DateOfBirth = models.DateField()
    Country = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    Nationality = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    Debut = models.ForeignKey("Movie", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CreatedBy = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    CreatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    ModifiedBy = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    ModifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    ClaimedBy = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
```

And, finally, my Cast model:

```
class Cast(models.Model):
    Movie = models.ForeignKey("Movie", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Actor = models.ForeignKey("Actor", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Character = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    Observations = models.TextField(max_length=50)
```

Right now, I can add content through Django admin, but it's awkward, because I can't add a cast in the Movie form. I have to go to the Cast form, and a character one by one

I've searched about customizing admin forms and whatnot, but I get a little confused.

Is there to create a form field in the Movie form to add the cast, preferably with three elements: one where you can choose the actor form the actors in the db, a text field to type the role and another text field to add a little observation?

Or is there a less convoluted way to organize this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can create a [**`TabularInline`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline) for the `Cast`:

```
class CastInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Cast
```

and then inject that into the `ModelAdmin` for the `Movie`:

```
class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    inlines = [CastInline]
```

Comment: Unbelievable! Exactly what I needed! Thank you!